# ¿Cómo ocultar columnas de una tabla en Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Aquí un ejemplo de una columna con sus respectivos detalles, lo que necesito es que muestre solo algunos datos, si alguien me pudiera ayudar se los agradecería.

[image: COLUMNA CON RESPECTIVO DETALLE]

Y este es mi código para mostrar el detalle desde una tabla boostrap.

```
<script>
    function detailFormatter(index, row) {
            var html = [];
            $.each(row, function (key, value) {
                    html.push('<td><b>' + key + ':</b> ' + value + '</td>');
            });
            return html.join('');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que nunca aparezcan en la tabla esos valores entonces podrás hacer una condición a la hora de agregar los datos a la misma:

```
$.each(row, function (key, value) {
    if(key != 'loQueSea')
          html.push('<td><b>' + key + ':</b> ' + value + '</td>');
    }
});
```

De esta forma, si la `key` es igual a `loQueSea` no se mostrará en tu tabla ya que no vas a agregar dicha columna.

En caso de que quieras ocultar algunas columnas según el tamaño de tu pantalla podrás usar las clases `.hidden` y `.visible` de Bootstrap. También tendrás que realizar una condición para establecersela según la `key` que tenga la columna correspondiente.

Aquí tienes una tabla con todos los posibles valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**[Documentación de Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)**.

Comment: ok amigo lo probare muchas gracias por la alluda

Comment: Gracias amigo Error404 realmente me a sido muy útil tu info.